# Extract 2 arguments from web page

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing, lxml.html

I want to extract 2 arguments (`title` and `href`) from `<a>` tag from a wikipedia page.

I want this output eg (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddley_Walker):

```
Canterbury Cathedral  
/wiki/Canterbury_Cathedral
```

The code:

```
import os, re, lxml.html, urllib

def extractplaces(hlink):
    connection = urllib.urlopen(hlink)
    places = {}

    dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())

    for name in dom.xpath('//a/@title'): # select the url in href for all a tags(links)
            print name
```

In this case i only get `@title`.

Comment: So what is your question? Are you facing any errors? If so, care to include that in your question?

Comment: I only get 1 arg, in that case only title.  
But i want the 2 arg title and href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get elements with tag `a` that have title attribute (instead of directly getting the `title` attribute).And then use `.attrib` for the element to get the attributes you need. Example -

```
for name in dom.xpath('//a[@title]'):
    print('title :',name.attrib['title'])
    print('href :',name.attrib['href'])
```